# Can a chrome extension access an iframe that is NOT same origin?

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy, content-script

I am writing an extension that opens an iframe on top of whatever page the user happens to be on.  I'd for the extension to access this frame directly, most likely using the chrome.runtime API.  I'd also like to avoid using a content script on this iframe for other reasons.  My iframe is loaded from "localhost", so my manifest.json has this property:

```
  //External access permissions
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "http://localhost/*",
    ]
  }
```

Using the information provided in this [tutorial from Google](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external-webpage), I'd like to have to extension contact the iframe using message passing.  Is this possible?